# Not getting ^STIN: response

Tags: putty, at-command, sim-toolkit

I have been accessing Sim Toolkit Applications from puTTY terminal using huawei e303f modem and a sim. I am writing AT commands specific to huawei modems. Basically right now, I am only trying to navigate sim toolkit menu. However, according to example in documentation, ^STIN: response is being sent by sim. But the same response I am not getting in my puTTY terminal. I am only getting "OK" response but no ^STIN: response. Here is my code---

```
AT
OK
AT^STSF=1
OK
AT^CMEE=2
COMMAND NOT SUPPORT
AT+CMEE=2
OK
AT^STGI=0,0
^STGI:0,8,"52204D656E75"
^STGI:1,8,"4E657773",0,
^STGI:2,8,"486F726F73636F7065",0,
^STGI:3,8,"437269636B6574",0,
^STGI:4,8,"456E7465727461696E6D656E74",0,
^STGI:5,8,"63616C6C65722074756E6573",0,
^STGI:6,8,"4D69737365642063616C6C20416C657274",0,
^STGI:7,8,"4F7468657273",0,
^STGI:8,8,"52204C697665",0,

OK
AT^STGR=0,0,1,3                  //accessing 3rd item
OK                              //in documentation, after OK, ^STIN:6,1 is also displayed but not in the terminal
AT^STGR=0,0,1,7
OK
```

Please Help! I am stuck!

Comment: After `AT^STGR=0,0,1,3` try `AT^STGI?`. This will show you the possible STGI values. Are you supposed to get the result as a SMS?